# Duplicate symbol for struct in header guarded file

Tags: c++

I am having a c++ linking problem. I am trying to define a Point2D struct for all of my other files to use. Here it is.

```
#ifndef Point2D_h
#define Point2D_h

#include <iostream>

struct Point2D {
    float x;
    float y;


    Point2D(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    Point2D() : x(0), y(0) {}

    Point2D operator+(const Point2D& a) const {
        return Point2D(a.x + x, a.y + y);
    }

    ….
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point2D& m) {
    return os << "(" << m.x << ", " << m.y << ")";
}

#endif /* Point2D_h */
```

The only problem is that I get a duplicate symbol Point2D error when I try to build. I am not sure why Point2D would be a duplicate symbol since it is header guarded

Here are all my other files, whether they are header guarded and whether they use Point2D and of course their imports:

Global.h (Header Guarded)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9000
```

Engine Core (Header Guarded)

```
#import "Global.h"
#import "Tests/EngineTests.hpp"
#import "Engine/Engine.hpp"
#import "Particle/Particle.hpp"
```

Tests.cpp (Uses Point2D)

```
#include "EngineTests.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "../Engine/Engine.hpp"
```

Tests.h

```
#include "Global.h"
```

Engine.cpp

```
#include "Engine.hpp"
#include <iostream>
```

Engine.hpp (Header guarded)

```
#include "Global.h"
#include "../Particle/ParticleManager.hpp"
```

Particle.cpp

```
#include "Particle.hpp"
#include <iostream>
```

Particle.h (Header guarded, uses Point2D)

```
#include "Global.h"
#include "../Math/Point.h"
```

ParticleManager.cpp

```
#include "ParticleManager.hpp"
#include <iostream>
```

ParticleManager.h (Header guarded)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Global.h"
#include "Particle.hpp"
```

And the linker says the following

```
duplicate symbol __ZlsRNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERK7Point2D in:
    …/arm64/Particle.o
    …larm64/Engine.o
duplicate symbol __ZlsRNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERK7Point2D in:
    …/Particle.o
    …/arm64/EngineTests.o
duplicate symbol __ZlsRNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERK7Point2D in:
    …/arm64/Particle.o
    …/ParticleManager.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

Comment: The error is for your `operator<<` function. Don't define functions in header files. (Also, header guards don't protect against linker errors.)

Comment: Header guards stop a header from being included multiple times in one compilation unit (or cpp file if you prefer), they don't prevent the header from being included when other files are being compiled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964819/function-already-defined-error-in-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469849/one-or-more-multiply-defined-symbols-found

Comment: One resolution is to add the keyword `inline` to the definition of `operator<<`. Another resolution is to just declare it in the header, and provide the definition in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

**Short-term** solution: use the inline keyword for functions defined in header files

```
inline Point2D operator+(const Point2D& a) const {
    return Point2D(a.x + x, a.y + y);
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point2D& m) {
    return os << "(" << m.x << ", " << m.y << ")";
}
```

**Long term**: Don't have any code inlined unless it's a measurable performance degradation. (Code in header files is forbidden on my team).  Have your header files as follows:

```
#ifndef Point2D_h
#define Point2D_h

#include <iostream>
struct Point2D {
    float x;
    float y;

    Point2D(float x, float y);    
    Point2D();

    Point2D operator+(const Point2D& a) const;

    ….
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point2D& m);
```

And a corresponding Point2d.cpp file:

```
Point2D::Point2D(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

Point2D::Point2D() : x(0), y(0) {}

Point2D::Point2D operator+(const Point2D& a) const {
    return Point2D(a.x + x, a.y + y);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point2D& m) {
    return os << "(" << m.x << ", " << m.y << ")";
}
```

Comment: I would switch what's “long term” and what's “short term”. E.g. separate compilation still lacks good tool support for browsing code, and using libraries structured that way is still a PITA.